# How to combine two datasets vertically in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a loop which generates dataframes with 2 columns in each. Now, when I try to append the dataframes vertically (stacking those vertically), the code adds the new dataframes horizontally when I use pd.concat within a loop. However, the results do not merge the columns (with same lenght properly). Instead, it adds 2 new columns for every loop iteration, creating a bunch on Nans. How to solve?

```
df_master=pd.DataFrame()
columns=list(df_master)

data=[]
for i in range(1,3):
        --do something and return a df2 with 2 columns
        data.append(df2)
            
df_master = pd.concat(data, axis=1)
df_master.head()
```

How do I compress the new 2 column for every iteration within one dataframe?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. Have you also upvoted my answer ?  If no, please consider also upvoting my answer by clicking the up arrow ▲ (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments)).   Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to keep the column labels of original dataframes, you can try renaming the column labels of each dataframe to the same (e.g. `0` and `1`) before concat, for example:

```
df_master = pd.concat([dfi.rename({old: new for new, old in enumerate(dfi.columns)}, axis=1) for dfi in data], ignore_index=True)
```

**Demo**

```
df1

   57  59
0   1   2
1   3   4


df2

   138  140
0   11   12
1   13   14


data = [df1, df2]

df_master = pd.concat([dfi.rename({old: new for new, old in enumerate(dfi.columns)}, axis=1) for dfi in data], ignore_index=True)


df_master

    0   1
0   1   2
1   3   4
2  11  12
3  13  14
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the problem is your columns have different names in each iteration, so you could easily solve it by calling `df2.rename()` and renaming it to the same names

Answer (score 0):

It works for me if I change axis to 0 inside the concat command.

```
df_master = pd.concat(data, axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas would fill empty cells with `NaNs` in each scenario and like the example you see below.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[11,12,13], 'col2': [21,22,23], 'col3':[31,32,33]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[111,112,113, 114], 'col2': [121,122,123,124]})
```

merge / join / concatenate data frames `[df1, df2]` vertically - add rows

```
pd.concat([df1,df2], ignore_index=True)
# output 

   col1  col2  col3
0    11    21  31.0
1    12    22  32.0
2    13    23  33.0
3   111   121   NaN
4   112   122   NaN
5   113   123   NaN
6   114   124   NaN
```

merge / join / concatenate data frames horizontally (aligning by index)

```
pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1)
# output
   col1  col2  col3  col1  col2
0  11.0  21.0  31.0   111   121
1  12.0  22.0  32.0   112   122
2  13.0  23.0  33.0   113   123
3   NaN   NaN   NaN   114   124
```